# Python PIL - plot points from lat, lng coordinates

Tags: python-imaging-library, mapping

I am near throwing in the towel on a problem and thought I'd ask here first to see if there is a solution.  I am attempting to plot custom icons on a map image converting lat,lng coords to pixels and pasting with PIL.  My method involves plotting these points relative to the centroid.

I have the following:

- image of map (w: 2800, h: 2600)
- Zoom level: 16.045383428216734
- Centroid (map zoomed to this point): [149.7985724, -35.4420469]
- Other points - [(149.79889 -35.44060), (149.79772 -35.44349)]

I have had the following results (note: i understand as the scrollbars show that my points in this case should be off by a few pixels and can fix later):

1. Using the below code I have produced this image. The orange boxes should lie over the circle markers.  Any help would be much appreciated.

image:[image]
result image:[image]

Code:

```
import math
from math import *
from math import pi, atan, sinh, log, tan, cos

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageChops, ImageDraw

def getDistance(y,x,lat,lng):
    p1 = (float(lat), float(lng))
    p2 = (float(y),float(x))
    distance = round(geodesic(p1, p2).meters,0)
    return distance

mapboxZoom = 16.045383428216734
snagDpi = 4
mapWidth = 700
mapHeight = 650
centroid = [149.7985724, -35.4420469]

schDfDict = {'lng': {1: 149.79889, 2: 149.7977248}, 'lat': {1: -35.4406, 2: -35.4434938}}
schDf = pd.DataFrame(schDfDict)
schDf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(schDf, geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(schDf['lng'].astype(float), schDf['lat'].astype(float))])

im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(img)))

metersPerPx = 156543.03392 * cos(centroid[1] * pi / 180) / 2.0 ** mapboxZoom
mapWidthKm = metersPerPx * mapWidth
mapHeightKm = metersPerPx * mapHeight

## multiply distances by snagDpi
snagMetersPerPx = metersPerPx / snagDpi

centroidPx = ((mapWidth * snagDpi) / 2, (mapHeight * snagDpi) / 2)

foreground = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ronan\\Downloads\\testIcon.png")

for index, row in schDf.reset_index().iterrows():

    prop = schDf.iloc[[index]]
    propX = prop.geometry.x.values[0]
    propY = prop.geometry.y.values[0]

    angle = degrees(atan((propX - centroid[0]) / (propY - centroid[1])))

    mDist = getDistance(centroid[1],centroid[0],propY,propX)

    pxDist = mDist / snagMetersPerPx

    ## radian
    alpha = angle * pi / 180

    xx = centroidPx[0] + (pxDist * cos(alpha))
    yy = centroidPx[1] + (pxDist * sin(alpha))

    im.paste(foreground, (round(xx),round(yy)), foreground)
```

Comment: It's often easiest to debug stuff like this by trying to place a marker at NorthEast, then SouthWest, then SouthEast corner because you immediately see if your x values are getting tainted by your y values or vice versa and if either is scaled incorrectly. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think the issue lies with my meters per pixel measurement. Not sure what I'm trying to do is possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's hard to see for outsiders immediately what goes wrong without diving deep in it. My advice is to write standalone functions that do this calculation for you, and then write test cases with some predefined values (like corners, center, and the points you're interested in). You can then quickly tweak your algorithm until you have it correct.